# Trying to make sense of my PCIe slots

Tags: pci-express, nvme

The following command gives me infos about my PCIe slots :

```
# lspci -vv | grep -E 'PCI bridge|LnkCap:'
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel (...) PCIe Controller (x16) (...)
        LnkCap:    Port #2, Speed 8GT/s, Width x16 (...)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel (...)
        LnkCap:    Port #17, Speed 8GT/s, Width x4 (...)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel (...)
        LnkCap:    Port #1, Speed 8GT/s, Width x1 (...)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel (...)
        LnkCap:    Port #3, Speed 8GT/s, Width x1 (...)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel (...)
        LnkCap:    Port #4, Speed 8GT/s, Width x1 (...)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel (...)
        LnkCap:    Port #5, Speed 8GT/s, Width x4 (...)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel (...)
        LnkCap:    Port #9, Speed 8GT/s, Width x4 (...)
        LnkCap:    Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x16 (...)
        LnkCap:    Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x16 (...)
        LnkCap:    Port #0, Speed 16GT/s, Width x4 (...)
        LnkCap:    Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1 (...)
```

Laptop is a 2017 Asus ROG G752VSK. [Specs](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Asus-G752VSK-77B07SB1.221140.0.html) states that is has two PCIe 3.0x4.

Why do I have so many slots in my output ? If I lookup [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#History_and_revisions), can I deduce that I have :

- 1 x PCIe 3.0 x16 (Speed 8GT/s, Width x16)
- 2 x PCIe 3.0 x4 (Speed 8GT/s, Width x4)
- 3 x PCIe 3.0 x1 (Speed 8GT/s, Width x1)

And what about the last bridge, which seems to have 5 ports, among them one that looks like a PCIe 4.0 x4 (Speed 16GT/s, Width x4) ?

I can't make any sense of it. I was expecting `lspci` to show the 2 PCIe 3.0x4 that I can physically identify in my laptop. Why so many other PCIe ports ?

[ EDIT, at u1686_grawity's request ]

```
# lspci -tvnn
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:5910]
           +-01.0-[01]--+-00.0  NVIDIA Corporation GP104BM [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile] [10de:1be1]
           |            \-00.1  NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f0]
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:a12f]
           +-14.2  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem [8086:a131]
           +-15.0  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:a160]
           +-15.1  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #1 [8086:a161]
           +-16.0  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:a13a]
           +-17.0  Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] [8086:a102]
           +-1b.0-[02]----00.0  Sandisk Corp Device [15b7:5030]
           +-1c.0-[03]--
           +-1c.2-[04]----00.0  Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3]
           +-1c.3-[05]----00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168]
           +-1c.4-[06-3e]--
           +-1d.0-[3f]----00.0  Micron/Crucial Technology Device [c0a9:540a]
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation CM238 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller [8086:a154]
           +-1f.2  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller [8086:a121]
           +-1f.3  Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller [8086:a171]
           \-1f.4  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus [8086:a123]
```

[ EDIT 2 ]

Basically, what I am trying to do is to find out a way to confirm that the two NVMe/PCIe slots are indeed 3.0x4.

In fact I want to apply that technique to another laptop I have : official specs said it had one Gen4x4 and one Gen4x2, and when I contacted them to identify each one, they told me their website was outdated, and in fact my laptop had two Gen4x4. So I was looking for a way to confirm that

[ EDIT 3, following @Mokubai's answer and comments ]

My grep added a few unrelated lines. This one is better :

```
# lspci -vv | grep 'PCI bridge' -A40 | grep -E 'PCI bridge|LnkCap:'
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel (...) PCIe Controller (x16) (...)
        LnkCap:    Port #2, Speed 8GT/s, Width x16 (...)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel (...)
        LnkCap:    Port #17, Speed 8GT/s, Width x4 (...)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel (...)
        LnkCap:    Port #1, Speed 8GT/s, Width x1 (...)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel (...)
        LnkCap:    Port #3, Speed 8GT/s, Width x1 (...)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel (...)
        LnkCap:    Port #4, Speed 8GT/s, Width x1 (...)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel (...)
        LnkCap:    Port #5, Speed 8GT/s, Width x4 (...)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel (...)
        LnkCap:    Port #9, Speed 8GT/s, Width x4 (...)
```

Combined with `lspci -tvnn`'s result, we can indeed come to the conclusion that the 2 NVMe slots are `1b.0` and `1d.0`, e.g. Sandisk (WD in my case) and Micron/Crucial, both at `Speed 8GT/s, Width x4`, e.g. Gen3x4.

Comment: Can you show a `lspci -tvnn`?

Comment: @u1686_grawity : done

Comment: If the drives are capable of exceeding 2 PCIe lanes worth of data transfer rate, then a speed test would show if they are using 4 PCIe lanes. (But that won't teach you anything about what the data you've gathered means.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slots and ports are different.

You apparently have multiple bridges which connect other devices in your system. At a guess there are PCIe ethernet, WiFi, SATA, NVMe, bluetooth and other devices connected to ports on various PCIe hubs.

PCIe is just a way to connect devices, those devices don't have to have a physical connector or slot, they can be connected directly to ports on a hub without having to use removable connectors.

---

<sub><sub>trying to summarise comments</sub></sub>

PCIe is used for a lot of things outside of just physical connectors. PCIe defines a method of encapsulating the PCI protocol inside a fast and efficient electrical interface. It is more than just the connectors you see and devices are often connected electrically without the use of the more obvious connectors.

Identifying devices from `lspci` is a bit hit and miss. It will (as far as I know) only show current link speed and not full capabilities, and `grep` can leave out important context. Many of your trailing lines could be related to other devices (which are showing link speed capabilities) but are not related to the device immediately above.

To use an educated guess I would suggest that your NVMe devices are

```
1b.0-[02]----00.0  Sandisk Corp Device [15b7:5030]
```

Note that Sandisk are a subsidiary of Western Digital and `lspci` may be using an internal "Vendor ID" list to match devices. I have a Western Digital NVMe SSD and it also reports a vendor ID of 15B7 in Windows. The other NVMe device is most likely

```
1d.0-[3f]----00.0  Micron/Crucial Technology Device [c0a9:540a]
```

The `Speed 8GT/s, Width x4` denotes a PCIe 3.0 interface (`8GT/s`) at the width you are expecting.

With that as a starting point you should hopefully be able to identify ports in your second laptop.

Comment: OK, I get it. I thought PCIe was only used for NVMe. Is there a way to find out which ports are those of my two NVMe drives ?

Comment: I would expect the NVMe devices to be the SanDisk and Micron devices in your extended listing in your question edit.

Comment: But just to confirm, PCIe is used for many things in modern systems because it is a fast interface that is electrically efficient in terms of being relatively easy to wire. PCIe is more about the communications and electrical protocols between devices. We have a standard set of connectors that fulfil the electrical requirements of PCIe, but those connectors are not mandatory to be used between devices.

Comment: I just updated my question to explain why exactly I am trying to identify the NVMe/PCIe ports. For the Micron (`1d.0`) I think you are probably right, because indeed one of my NVMe is a "Crucial by Micron". As for the Sandisk (`1b.0`), I am surprised because my second NVMe is a WD_BLACK SN850X.

Comment: Also, why does the Micron bridge (`1d.0`) show so many ports ? Among them, one with `Speed 16GT/s, Width x4`, which are the specs of a Gen4 (the official specs of that laptop states that it has two Gen3x4).

Comment: @ChennyStar Sandisk are a brand/subsidiary of Western Digital and lspci may be matching the device vendor (15B7) and not showing the identity reported by the device. On my PC a WD Black is reported as VEN_15B7. https://www.westerndigital.com/en-gb/brand/sandisk

Comment: OK. So the two NVMe slots are identified (Micron and Sandisk). Sandisk (`1b.0`) indeed seems to be a Gen3x4 (as per `Speed 8GT/s, Width x4`). As for the Micron (`1d.0`), I'll do some speed tests to find out if it's a Gen3x4 (as per the laptop's specs) or rather a Gen4x4  (as per `Speed 16GT/s, Width x4`). Any idea why the Micron (`1d.0`) has so many ports ?

Comment: @ChennyStar I would also not really trust a `grep`ed output as it doesn't show full context. those other `16GT/s x4` and `8GT/s x16` lines could well be being reported from something else. and not from the same group as the device itself. You need the full output to be sure. from what you see I would only trust the first line out which suggests that both devices are operating at 8GT x4 which would be PCIe 3.

Comment: Wow, you are sooo right... my grep was a bad idea .... a ` lspci -vv | grep 'PCI bridge' -A 20` is much better. I'll update the question to clarify this. THANKS, mystery solved...

Answer (score 1):

The output you show does not describe *slots* – it describes *links.* A link may go over a physical card slot (e.g. the SSD M.2 slot), but it may also be directly wired to another chip, or it may go over something like Thunderbolt, etc. There may even be links that aren't wired to anything at all.

The specs of your laptop only document the external (user-facing) slots, but PCI is not exclusively about external slots – there are *a lot* of internal devices, both inside the CPU/SoC and elsewhere on the mainboard, that communicate via PCI-Express, such as your Wi-Fi interface or your discrete GPU or your entire USB host controller. (It's similar to how your laptop webcam or your Bluetooth module are internal USB devices and have their own "ports" on the USB host.)

Computer specifications usually do not document such internal connections as it's almost never relevant to the user whether something is connected via USB or PCIe or SPI if they cannot repurpose that connection for their own needs anyway.

(Also, even though your Wi-Fi/Bluetooth card is probably in a removable M.2 slot that carries PCIe+USB, that's rarely documented because the manufacturer doesn't like you changing that card; many laptops only accept specific models there.)

Comment: Thanks. Yes I get this. But that doesn't help me in identifying the specs of the two NVMe PCIe ports. How can I find out those specs (e.g., the generation and number of lanes) ? (I updated my question to explain why I am trying to do this)

Comment: I'm not sure of the best way to determine that, but what I'd do at first is check `dmesg` to see if it warns about a particular slot being _insufficient_ for the device that's installed – something like `pci 0000:01:00.0: 32.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 2.5 GT/s PCIe x16 link at 0000:00:01.0 (capable of 126.016 Gb/s with 8.0 GT/s PCIe x16 link)`. If you don't have any messages with "...limited by...", that still doesn't tell you the maximum capabilities of the slot, but at least you'll know that the slot is suitable for the SSD that you have installed.

Comment: OK yes good idea. That and a speed test should be enough to confirm the NVMe slots capabilities